# Range.Insert only works when data already exists

Tags: excel, vba, insert

I'm trying to insert a range to a spreadsheet.  The code works fine, but only if the destination sheet already has data in it.  If the sheet is empty, then the range doesn't get inserted.  Any ideas?

```
    If rng2 Is Nothing Then
    Else
        rng2.Copy
        Worksheets(Name).Activate
        ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown

    End If
```

Comment: When I try your code with the destination sheet having no data, it works fine.  Are you getting an error?  If so, which one?  And on which line?

Comment: It doesn't return an error.  I've had to resort to checking if the sheet is empty first, then deciding to paste or insert.

Comment: By chance do you have an `On Error Resume Next` statement included in your code?  If so, remove it and try running your code again.  It might reveal an error, if there is one.

Comment: As Domenic already says, I can confirm that code fragment _does_ work irrespective of if there is data on the destination sheet or not.  Without further context this Q is unanswerable.